# Connect to another computer's local ms sql server from Mac

Tags: php, ios, sql, sql-server

I know there are a lot questions and answers for connecting to another computer's sql server.

But I couldn't find right step by step.. to connect my another computer (windows 10) pc's sql server 2016 database.

1. I enabled tcp/ip. IPALL TCP Port is 1433 by Sql Server Configuration Manager.
2. I restarted SQL Server & SQL Server Browser and they all are set as automatic
3. I have database named `TestData` and table name `dbo.Users` in another pc windows10
4. In Windows pc I can open SSMS 2016 and easily connect to local db by Windwos Authentication. I thought I have to use Sql Server authentication from my Macbook Pro so I created a user login name `codeinflash` with password under `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB\Security\Logins
5. I am not 100 percent sure above step 4 is necessary to connect from my Macbook pro.
6. Now... I need advice to connect to my another computer's local db SQL SERVER from my Macbook pro

I have have XAMPP installed on my Macbook pro and tested MYSQL (not MSSQL) connection through PHP and it worked! I could POST something to my Macbook Pro's local MYSql. I followed this tutorial [swift ios php mysql tutorial](https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-php-mysql-tutorial/)

I knew the tutorial was for mysql. I never done db connection so I followed the tutorial somewhat I wnated to learn connecting to local db. In another PC (Windows10) I have SQL SERVER2016 running When I run query `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` I get `STEVEKIMASUS\LOCALDB#XXXXX`

Now I want to connect to another computer's local db..
Where I put my webservice/api like php so I can talk to another pc's local db?

I hope.. I explained my situation well..

Please help me.. step by step would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: is it a 'ms local db' or is it 'sql-server' ? A local db is sql-server without the services running and cannot be connected to from another machine

Comment: The tutorial from your question is for mysql, not for sql-server. Are you aware of that ?

Comment: @GuidoG I knew the tutorial was for mysql. I never done db connection so I followed the tutorial somewhat I wnated to learn connecting to local db. In another PC (Windows10) I have SQL SERVER2016 running When I run query `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` I get `STEVEKIMASUS\LOCALDB#XXXXX`

Comment: @GuidoG How can I make services for anotherpc's local db..? So I can connect from my Mac?

Comment: you keep saying local db which is confusing. You have Sql-Server and you have another version of Sql-Server called "LocalDB". The latter cannot be connected to from another machine. I guess you mean the normal Sql-Server, not the "localDB" ?

Comment: I have no experience with connecting to sql-server from a mac. But if you are using "LocalDB" then it does not matters because you cannot connect to it anyway from another machine as far as i know